# Array does not have an objectAtindex member

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I'm building a simple Swift CoreData table view app. I have managed to successfully save the data to the database and reload the data in a table view. The next thing I want to do is edit this data. By tapping on a table cell/row I will be bale to edit the data by passing the details to another view controller and populate some textfields. But I'm having trouble on selecting the right array index. In Objective-C it was easier with an NSMUtableArray (I think).

My array is defined like so

`var myList: Array<AnyObject> = []`
An array suitable for the return type of executeFetchRequest()

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {

    if segue.identifier == "Edit" {
       var data: NSManagedObject = (myList.objectAtIndex(self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow().row))
    }
}
```

What is the Swift equivalent of `objectAtIndex`? (if this is the right question)

And this is the Error I get:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use subscript syntax, passing the index of the value you want to retrieve within square brackets immediately after the name of the array:

```
myList[self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow().row]
```

Comment: Exactly what I was after. Thanks @igor